# Single window mode in xsane

Tags: sane

Is it possible to use `xsane` in a single window mode (just like in `gimp` since version 2.8)? If it's not possible by default is there any compile option to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately xsane is not capable of running on a single window as GIMP does.

Even running it through GIMP, it will use its own interface rather than GIMP's.

At this point there's only a few things left to do:
- Arm yourself of patience, and divert your request directly at either the [author himself](http://www.xsane.org/xsane-contact.html) or the [SANE mailing list](http://www.xsane.org/xsane-mailinglist.html) (where you might discover the question's not new)
- If you know how to code, and got time, you could help the author by providing patches to him to create a single-window mode for xsane.

Please update the post in case you decide to take action, so people landing here might find an update to it.